# Sometimes Exists property is not supported

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I'm getting a really frustrating error that sometimes comes up and sometimes it runs through without a problem. My code is:

```
function killProcesses(processes) { // A string array of process names.
  for (i = 0; i < processes.length; i++) {
    var process = Sys.WaitProcess(processes[i])

    if (process.Exists) { // Sometimes the script will crash right here
      process.Terminate()
    }
}
```

Since I made the function I have always passed the exact same process names in, sometimes they are started others they aren't, that's never been a problem. But other times it will crash while running and tell me `Object doesn't support this property or method`. Like I said, this function and the line that calls it have never been changed, so I don't understand why only sometimes it fails.

I've gotten this in other parts of my scripts before, so I wonder if it might be related or there's just something in general wrong with my system. What really baffles me is that `Exists` should always exist on everything, so why is it sometimes just not there?

Answer (score 2):

The `Sys.WaitProcess(ProcessName)` method should either return the process found or an empty stub object with only property `Exists` with a value `false` if the process is not found. It doesn't matter if the process is found, it should be ok to use `Exists` to check if the process is found.

I have the same problem with control objects as result value of the `Find` method and it is widespread for all of the objects returned from the `Find` method.

I have found a workaround:

If accessing a different property (e.g `Name`) before accessing `Exists`, there is no error.

```
obj.Name; // Add this to prevent error in obj.Exists below:
if (obs.Exists)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

This only works if the objects are expected. In my case, they are. If the expected object is not found, `obj.Name` will throw an error which is ok as expected.

In the case where the object may be expected not to be found, you would be stuck if `Exists` does not work as the result value is not null or not empty and `obj.Name` will throw an error which you want to avoid and the only condition you can check is `obj.Exists`.

However, it may be worth trying to see if this works for process object if the process is found.

Comment: Thanks RobC for making the names of methods and properties in code formats. This is my first post and I need to learn how to use code formats.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could protect for null by having

If (process && process.Exists)

I would also loop down from the top just in case the process termination is affecting your process list.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this code is that when you terminate the first process, indexes of the rest processes are reduced. This version of the code is better:

```
function killProcess(pName) {
  var p = Sys.WaitProcess(pName, 5000, 1);
  while (p.Exists) {
    p.Terminate();
    while (p.Exists)
      Sys.Delay(50);
    p = Sys.WaitProcess(pName, 5000, 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why `.Exists` crashes my script. If I were to use your suggestion, it would still randomly crash when it hits that line.